# Need to parse data from xml to shell script

Tags: shell-script, xml, xmllint

Need to parse data from xml to shell script one aft another

```
Requriment :- we need to take <FileSetfolder> as one record. XML may contain many <FileSetFolder> from Each <FileSetFolder> record. 
we need to extract <path> and <Filetypes> and archive all the files which are with extension type as <Filetypes> 
need help in approach for this requirement

ex:- for first <FileSetfolder>
    Archive_path = D:\apache-2.4.10\htdocs
    Filetypes =(rep,zip,mnt)

    need to archive files in $Archive_path which have $Filetypes (rep,zip,mnt)

    then it should take next <FileSetfolder>
```

XML:-

```
<SourceFolder>
    <FileSetFolder>
      <Path>D:\apache-2.4.10\htdocs</Path>
      <FileType>rep</FileType>
      <FileType>zip</FileType>
      <FileType>mnt</FileType>
    </FileSetFolder>
    <FileSetFolder>
      <Path>D:\Download\ROSXcenterAutoArchive\ArchiveStorage\archive</Path>
      <FileType>mnt</FileType>
      <FileType>952230</FileType>
    </FileSetFolder>
  </SourceFolder>
```

Comment: Could you please also show the relevant part of the XML file?

Comment: could you at least provide an example of your output ?

Comment: @kiwy 

we need to take <FileSetfolder> as one record. XML may contain may <FileSetFolder>

from Each <FileSetFolder> record we need to extract <path> and <Filetypes> and archive all the files which are with extension type as <Filetypes>

need help in approach for this requirement

Comment: @VinayGowda please edit your quesiton, comments are temporary and could get deleted.

Comment: @Kiwy 

I have updated question with req and expected o/p

Comment: @Kusalananda can you please help regarding approach to solve above issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (sometimes install as `xmlstarlet` rather than `xml`):

```
paths=( $( xml sel -t -v '//FileSetFolder/Path' file.xml ) )

for path in "${paths[@]}"; do
    filetypes=( $( xml sel -t -v "//FileSetFolder[Path=\"$path\"]/FileType" file.xml ) )

    for filetype in "${filetypes[@]}"; do
            printf 'Path "%s" has a filetype "%s"\n' "$path" "$filetype"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
Path "D:\apache-2.4.10\htdocs" has a filetype "rep"
Path "D:\apache-2.4.10\htdocs" has a filetype "zip"
Path "D:\apache-2.4.10\htdocs" has a filetype "mnt"
Path "D:\Download\ROSXcenterAutoArchive\ArchiveStorage\archive" has a filetype "mnt"
Path "D:\Download\ROSXcenterAutoArchive\ArchiveStorage\archive" has a filetype "952230"
```

Comment: In first iteration i need to get one record at time

Comment: @VinayGowda I don't understand what you mean by "in the first iteration".

Comment: like 
path=D:\apache-2.4.10\htdocs
filetypes=(rep,zip,mnt)

Comment: actually xml is input for shell script. script should read one record at a time and it should archive all files types mentioned in that record set... it next iteration it should take 2nd record set

Comment: i have updated requirement can you let me know the approach to solve this issue

Comment: @VinayGowda I believe that the only thing my answer is missing is the archiving bit, but since I don't know what type of archiving you are using or wanting to use, I can't comment further on that.

Comment: looks a lot like homework and the more you add the more I feel homework in my bones